# Making one margin bigger to allow margin notes in KOMA script

Tags: margins, koma-script, marginpar, typearea

I want to add margin notes using KOMA script's `\marginline`. I don't want to get into the tricky business of manually setting a lot of typearea lengths myself, I just want to make the outside margin a little bigger to allow notes. Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to delve into `typearea`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, changing only the outside margin and leaving the other margins alone would destroy the page layout as envisioned by the author of `KOMA-script` (see chapter 2 of the manual). However, the manual offers some special advice for the treatment of margin notes: Set the class option `mpinclude=true` which will treat margin notes as part of the text block. Additionally, allow the notes to partially protude into the margin by adjusting the `\marginparwidth` length.

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.67\marginparwidth}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Some text.\marginline{\blindtext}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: if you call `mpinclude` with `\KOMAoptions` you will need to `\recalctypearea` to get the effect.

Answer (score 2):

A natural way would be something like `BCOR=12mm,DIV=calc,twoside`(mparhack is useful see the notes inside documentation).
If it's not enough, you can decide for a value for the DIV option and you can change BCOR. I put some `\blindtext`to see the use of BCOR in the next pages

```
\documentclass[BCOR=12mm,DIV=calc,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}      
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{mparhack} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}
\blindtext
Some text.\marginline{margin note lo ... oong}
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use `utf8x` only, if you really, really need it and `utf8` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

KOMA offers the addmargin environment where you can simply specify a length to increase the margin

```
\begin{addmargin}[left indentation]{indentation}
content
\end{addmargin}
```

Although I think the intention was to provide a environment for short paragraphs that need extra margins it might as well just work fine for the whole document

Comment: It does not work well for the whole document. `addmargin` is a list environment. And list environments have several side effects for other commands and environment.